# Simulating a mouse button press on Qt 5.3 only works the first time

Tags: c++, qt

I've written at QT5/QML application that I wish to be able to control remotely from a web browser. I'm sending a screen shot out to the browser and receiving position as x,y in return. I've written a C++ class to do this.

When I start the application, the image comes up and the first click from the browser works. The second does not work. If I click anywhere in the application, I see the button press happen on the screen, and then the remote press will work one more time.
I suspect the problem is that the focus changes and it's not being reset properly until I click on the actual application.

I'm using QGuiApplicatiop and so far haven't been able to get anythong useful out of itemAt or widgetAt so I can send the event to the appropriate object.

Here's a code snippet to show what I'm doing.

```
void Wremote::mClick(int x, int y ) {
    QPointF *pos = new  QPointF((qreal)x,(qreal)y);

    QWindowList wl = QGuiApplication::allWindows();
    _mwindow = wl[0];

    QMouseEvent pevent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,
        *pos, Qt::LeftButton
        ,Qt::LeftButton, 0);

    QMouseEvent revent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease,
        *pos, Qt::LeftButton
        ,Qt::LeftButton, 0);

    QApplication::instance() ->sendEvent(_mwindow, &pevent);
    QApplication::processEvents();
    QApplication::instance() ->sendEvent(_mwindow, &revent);
    QApplication::processEvents();  
}
```

This is my first foray into integrating Qt with C++. The bulk of the application uses pyotherside.

Any pointers to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but as a side note:  you're leaking memory with the above code -- you allocate (pos) using the new operator and then never delete it.  You'd be better off allocating (pos) on the stack:  QPointF pos(x,y);    (and then change *pos to pos in the QMouseEvent arguments lists)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My C++ skills are between rusty and non-existent. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution if not an elegant one.

```
void Wremote::mClick(int x, int y ) {         
    QTest::mouseClick(_mwindow,Qt::LeftButton,0,QPoint(x,y),-1);
}
```